# Is Apache::Request (old perl/apache) the same as HTTP::Request (new perl/Apache)?

Tags: perl, apache, apache2, mod-perl, apache2-module

Hello Perl warriors.

I'm totally new to the language and have been placed on a interesting project of porting an application that was originally written for Apache 1.3 (and the older Perl), to RHEL / CentOS 6 with Apache 2.2.x and mod_perl.

As for calling in lib's:

is

Apache::Request (old perl/apache) the same as HTTP::Request (Apache2, mod_perl)?

Additionally, if anyone has any resources they have found to be particularly useful during a perl upgrade / porting project, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [HTTP::Request](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aRequest) is part of the [LWP](https://www.metacpan.org/module/LWP) ecosystem and is used for constructing client-side HTTP requests for Perl HTTP clients.

You're probably looking for [Apache2::Request](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Apache2%3a%3aRequest) which is part of the libapreq distribution for Apache 2.

Comment: Thank you.  I did a little more digging and found the RPM that corresponds to these modules.  (yum install perl-libapreq2)